# Android set widget background

Tags: android, background-image

In my drawable-hdpi folder i have 4 image files (.png) to serve as the background of awidget. By default android:background="@drawable/goldgreenbg" is set for the LinearLayout. I created a preferences screen to let the user change the background.
How to do that? I would like to use this code for it:

```
      if (listpref.equals("color1"))
          {
          Toast.makeText(EditPreferences.this,  "Black" + listpref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }

else if (listpref.equals("color2"))
          {
              Toast.makeText(EditPreferences.this,  "Brown" + listpref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
```

Update:
Where shall i put this code to?
MainActivity.java: for the activity
UpdateService.java: for the widget
EditPreferences.java: for the preferences
Main.xml includes the listview and widgetlayout is id of it.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String listpref = preferences.getString("listPref", "n/a");              
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.widgetlayout);
  if (listpref.equals("color1"))
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Black" + listpref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ll.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackbg));
  }
  else if (listpref.equals("color2"))
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Brown" + listpref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ll.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brownbg));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

EditPreferences.java:

```
final Preference listpref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("listPref");
        listpref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
        {
         public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference p, Object newValue) 
         {
          String color = (String) newValue;

          if (color.equals("color1"))
          {
              RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(EditPreferences.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview, Color.rgb(208, 202, 202));
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview2, Color.WHITE);
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview3, Color.rgb(176, 175, 175));
             // updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, ((BitmapDrawable)EditPreferences.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.forestbg)).getBitmap());
              updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ImageView01, R.drawable.blacktrans);            
              ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(EditPreferences.this, HelloWidget.class);
              AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(EditPreferences.this);
              manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
 }
          else if (color.equals("color2"))
          {
              RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(EditPreferences.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview, Color.rgb(23, 81, 11));
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview2, Color.rgb(232, 232, 107));
              updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_textview3, Color.rgb(23, 81, 11));
              updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, ((BitmapDrawable)EditPreferences.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.goldgreenbg)).getBitmap());
              // updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ImageView01, R.drawable.goldgreenbgf);           
              ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(EditPreferences.this, HelloWidget.class);
              AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(EditPreferences.this);
              manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
  }
  return true;
         }
        });
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
          getPrefs();
}
     private void getPrefs() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            ListPreference = prefs.getString("listPref", "nr1");
     }
```

This way it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you allready have the `LinearLayout` on your screen (using `setContentView`), you can change the background quite easily like so:

```
yourLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackbg));
```

(and get that layout using `findViewById()` ofcourse )

Comment: Looks good. And where to put this code? I put it in the EditPreferences.java (which extends PreferenceActivity), but it is not working (toast appears only when i first click my "settings" btn, but if i click it again and choose another color there is not toast msg..
I also have MainActivity.java for the activity and UpdateService.java for the widget. I tried to put in the onCreate method of UpdateService.java, not working either.

Comment: assuming you've got that preference saved, you can put it after your "setContentView()" call.

Comment: I updated the main post. I am not sure if i have to put the code in the MainActivity.java and whether i have to put some code in UpdateService.java..

Comment: Again, it's really hard to say, but you have to load the xml that has the linearLayout you want to change somewhere. After you load the xml, then your layout is available to load with findContentView, and then you can set the background. Just like i said before.

Comment: Isn't this what i have in my code? If i put this in MainActivity.java, only the background image appears in the activity, which is wrong, coz i cannot see the whole activity, moreover it should have been the widget that changed not the activity...

Comment: Yes it is, so I don't know what you are still asking :)

Comment: I opened a new topic for it, because i think i wasn't clear enough of my problem.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912858/android-listpreference-and-widget-background)